# Plot confidence interval of average polynomial fit from coefficients

Tags: confidence-interval, data-visualization, regression-coefficients, fitting, polynomial

I am studying the propagation of a wave and to do that I want to follow the position of my maxima over time. In order to do that I thought to fit a polynomial on the data of each replicate, then save the coefficients of each polynomial and then calculate an average polynomial by averaginf the coefficients. I am doing this in this way:

First I fit a 6th grade polynomial on my data

```
model0 <- lm(tdfmean2$meand ~ poly(tdfmean2$alltimes,6, raw = T) -1)
```

the -1 forces the poly to pass from 0,0 ,tdfmean2 is my data frame, meand is the mean position of the max at each time point and alltimes in the column with the time

then I can extract the coefficients of my model

```
cf0 = coef(model0)
cf0
```

and then I can rebuild an equation and save some value to plot my curve for this replicate.

```
xm <- 0:190
y0 <- cf0[1]*xm + cf0[2]*(xm^2) + cf0[3]*(xm^3) + cf0[4]*(xm^4) + cf0[5]*(xm^5) + cf0[6]*(xm^6)
model0_df <- data.frame(cbind(xm,y0))
```

What I want to do next is to store the coefficients of each replicate and then calculate the average coefficients across all replicates:

```
    NA. genotype sample_name    condition    coeff1      coeff2        coeff3        coeff4        coeff5        coeff6
1    1     col0           2 no treatment 10.645219 -0.27991785  0.0046284484 -4.157269e-05  1.822185e-07 -3.048687e-10
2    2     col0           3 no treatment 10.553457 -0.21942501  0.0020468207 -4.675756e-06 -3.078219e-08  1.234126e-10
3    3     col0           5 no treatment 11.318681 -0.22596993  0.0028321289 -2.070399e-05  7.901194e-08 -1.206557e-10
4    4     col0           6 no treatment 10.416127 -0.19350901  0.0023198163 -1.613161e-05  5.853231e-08 -8.562595e-11
5    5     col0           7 no treatment 10.365075 -0.24591990  0.0036110039 -2.861296e-05  1.131259e-07 -1.757093e-10
6    6     col0           8 no treatment  8.073907 -0.13986866  0.0015194720 -9.020292e-06  2.749597e-08 -3.435694e-11
7    7     col0           9 no treatment 10.951157 -0.23504111  0.0031379152 -2.335273e-05  8.910691e-08 -1.361389e-10
8    8     col0          11 no treatment  7.907365 -0.12264808  0.0005476001  8.681364e-06 -8.824417e-08  2.153590e-10
9    9     col0          12 no treatment  7.956929 -0.08984904  0.0005133731 -6.733359e-07 -5.829500e-09  1.836931e-11
10  10     col0          13 no treatment 10.092490 -0.18451556  0.0021726107 -1.450010e-05  4.973589e-08 -6.802710e-11
11  11     col0          15 no treatment  7.752161 -0.09695462  0.0008062611 -3.613068e-06  6.129860e-09  1.226553e-12
12  12     col0          16 no treatment  9.158635 -0.16035016  0.0018217135 -1.214841e-05  4.368299e-08 -6.493449e-11
13  13     col0          18 no treatment  9.816227 -0.19022842  0.0023592866 -1.664531e-05  6.099036e-08 -9.028776e-11
14  14     col0          19 no treatment 10.460419 -0.17301229  0.0018772190 -1.259279e-05  4.806232e-08 -7.796818e-11
15  15     col0          20 no treatment  8.989490 -0.20399518  0.0030250021 -2.412503e-05  9.513354e-08 -1.459567e-10
16  16     col0          21 no treatment  6.971790 -0.10011748  0.0010670835 -6.887514e-06  2.416397e-08 -3.570303e-11
17  17     col0          22 no treatment  7.408617 -0.11316713  0.0009324162 -2.494966e-06 -5.535340e-09  2.669259e-11
18  18     col0          23 no treatment  6.975045 -0.02370698 -0.0009177655  1.306468e-05 -6.568632e-08  1.154866e-10
19  19     col0          25 no treatment  7.505218 -0.02504451 -0.0008343186  1.173565e-05 -5.824071e-08  1.010885e-10
20  20     col0          27 no treatment  7.885268 -0.08297538  0.0002999775  2.714420e-06 -2.549118e-08  5.613721e-11

dfcol0_long <- gather(dfcol0[,5:10], factor_key=TRUE)

dfcol0_long

dfcol0_m <- data.frame(dfcol0_long%>% group_by(key)%>%
summarise(mean= mean(value), sd= sd(value), max = max(value),min = min(value)))

> dfcol0_m
 key          mean           sd           max           min
1 coeff1  9.060164e+00 1.469654e+00  1.131868e+01  6.971790e+00
2 coeff2 -1.553108e-01 7.210264e-02 -2.370698e-02 -2.799179e-01
3 coeff3  1.688303e-03 1.420367e-03  4.628448e-03 -9.177655e-04
4 coeff4 -1.007772e-05 1.393039e-05  1.306468e-05 -4.157269e-05
5 coeff5  2.987906e-08 6.639202e-08  1.822185e-07 -8.824417e-08
6 coeff6 -3.412303e-11 1.207775e-10  2.153590e-10 -3.048687e-10
```

**At this point, I can rebuild my average polynomial using those coeffficients and plot it. But I would also like it to have a shaded area around the curve that denotes the confidence interval. Is that possible to do starting from these data?**

I tried to plot wit a ribbon using the code below, but the result is a disaster and the shaded area in unreasonably wide, covering an aread that is well far away from the place where all my replicates are. **Any idea why is this happening?**

```
upperCF <- dfcol0_m$mean + dfcol0_m$sd
lowerCF <- dfcol0_m$mean - dfcol0_m$sd

dfcol0_m <- cbind.data.frame(dfcol0_m, upperCF)
dfcol0_m <- cbind.data.frame(dfcol0_m, lowerCF)

> dfcol0_m
     key          mean           sd           max           min       upperCF       lowerCF
1 coeff1  9.060164e+00 1.469654e+00  1.131868e+01  6.971790e+00  1.052982e+01  7.590510e+00
2 coeff2 -1.553108e-01 7.210264e-02 -2.370698e-02 -2.799179e-01 -8.320817e-02 -2.274135e-01
3 coeff3  1.688303e-03 1.420367e-03  4.628448e-03 -9.177655e-04  3.108670e-03  2.679360e-04
4 coeff4 -1.007772e-05 1.393039e-05  1.306468e-05 -4.157269e-05  3.852664e-06 -2.400811e-05
5 coeff5  2.987906e-08 6.639202e-08  1.822185e-07 -8.824417e-08  9.627107e-08 -3.651296e-08
6 coeff6 -3.412303e-11 1.207775e-10  2.153590e-10 -3.048687e-10  8.665450e-11 -1.549006e-10

xm <- 0:190
y <- dfcol0_m[1,2]*xm + dfcol0_m[2,2]*(xm^2) + dfcol0_m[3,2]*(xm^3) + dfcol0_m[4,2]*(xm^4) + dfcol0_m[5,2]*(xm^5) + dfcol0_m[6,2]*(xm^6)
y_upper <- dfcol0_m[1,6]*xm + dfcol0_m[2,6]*(xm^2) + dfcol0_m[3,6]*(xm^3) + dfcol0_m[4,6]*(xm^4) + dfcol0_m[5,6]*(xm^5) + dfcol0_m[6,6]*(xm^6)
y_lower <- dfcol0_m[1,7]*xm + dfcol0_m[2,7]*(xm^2) + dfcol0_m[3,7]*(xm^3) + dfcol0_m[4,7]*(xm^4) + dfcol0_m[5,7]*(xm^5) + dfcol0_m[6,7]*(xm^6)

col0_avgpol <- cbind.data.frame(xm, y, y_upper, y_lower)

plot_avgpol <- ggplot(data=dftotal, aes(x=xm, y=y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y_lower, ymax=y_upper), linetype=2, alpha=0.1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,180), ylim=c(0,520)) + xlab("Time (s)") + ylab("Distance (um)") +
  ggtitle (paste("Average distance of the maxima from the centre over time", '\n', "experiment 1, N=20")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: Regression splines would probably be better in this situation.  For either restricted cubic splines or regular (not hard to interpret orthogonal polynomials as you are using) polynomials, the R `rms` package makes such plots easy to do, with pointwise or simultaneous confidence bands.  See my [RMS course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).

Comment: It's hard to see why averaging the coefficients of sets of polynomials has much, if anything, to do with your original question of data analysis.  What is the justification of this procedure?  And what exactly is the desired confidence interval intended to represent?  What parameter of your model are you bounding with it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. For Frank, Initially I chose polynomials over splines beacause it seemed more intuitive for me how to handle the equation... If there is no way to do what I want to do with the polynomial I will turn to splines. Why would you say splines are better in this case? For whuber, The idea of averaging the coefficients came to me beacuse I want to draw an average curve that represents all my data and I have various replicates of the same experiment. So for each replicate I fit a polynomial, then I save the coeeficients and then I calculate an average polynomial.

Comment: For whuber, part 2 - I am looking for a shaded area around my curve beacuse I need to visually compare curves coming from expreiments with different conditions... so roughly in my head if the average courve of the experiment B was falling out of the shaded area of the average curve of the experiment A then I would think that actually there is a difference between my two conditions... I am not sure this is the best way to see a difference between two curves, I am just exploring ways and looking for advices

Comment: Consider using the median coefficient values. rather than the mean (average) values.